# I want to integrate micronaut functionality in sample oneM2M project and to calculate the execution time of the functions

Tags: java, maven, osgi, micronaut

I am not to integrate micronaut in sample oneM2M osgi project .I want to calculate the execution time of the functions using micronaut,but micronaut is  running as a seperate application. But not with osgi project . I have created the plugin named **org.eclipse.om2m.sample.ipe** and added the plugin in the mn-cse module .

I have created the sample plugin in mn-cse and added the micronaut functionality in that but the annotations like singleton,async and many more are not resolved. My micronaut functinality is running in the seperate project but not in the plugin one . What should I need to do ?
[error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDuV0.png) .If someone can tell me how to integrate micronaut with oneM2M sample project then it would be great !